# Why does this grep -F not work?

Tags: grep, ubuntu-14.04

I've used `grep -F` extensively at work (CentOS) to ignore regex pattern in the match. Now here's what I'm trying at home (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ cat file

Here is
the -F
you were looking 
for!

~$ grep -F '-F' file
_
```

The underscore is meant to show a blinking cursor, as if it's waiting for input. Could it be because Ubuntu's `grep` doesn't follow all POSIX switches (I read that `-F` was specified by POSIX) or am I making a mistake somewhere?'

===== Update ======

Interestingly, it fails only when there's a newline following `-F`. If you change the text to, say, `-F option`, then the line matches. A bug in grep?

Comment: @TomZych: nope, `--` to mark the end of arguments isn't the problem.  That would only help if you had a file with `-F` as the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the same argument twice has no effect, so

```
grep -F '-F' file
```

is the same as `grep -F file`, which of course searches for the fixed-string `file` in its standard input.

The single-quotes are a red-herring.  They protect the `-F` from any expansion by the shell (like glob-expansion, variable expansion, command substitution, etc.), and are removed by the shell before `grep` sees the `-F`.

What you need to do is use `grep`'s `-e pattern` argument:

```
grep -F -e '-F'  file
```

Given that context, the `-F` will be interpreted as the pattern.  The single-quotes are still redundant.  You could single-quote every other arg.  I left them in because it helps humans come to the right conclusion at first glance, and it's generally not bad practice to quote stuff that *could* contain shell meta-characters in a future version of the script, even if it's currently safe.